# Permissions problems on OS X Leopard; does this indicate tampering or malware?

Tags: osx-leopard, file-permissions

Basically, it looks like a bunch of permissions had been changed from `rwx------` to `rwxrwxrwx` (or pretty close to that); some of which involve Java for Mac, I think. I recently did an Archive & Install of OS X 10.5.

Does this indicate any tampering with my system or any malware infection?

Here are the repairs:

```
Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVD.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/FRSettings.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/FRSources.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/Movies.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/Music.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/Photos.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/Podcasts.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app/Contents/PlugIns/TV.frappliance/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackRow.framework/Versions/A/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/RemoteDesktop.menu/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/CodeResources", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/CodeResources", should be -rw-rw-r-- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Info.plist", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Info.plist", should be -rw-rw-r-- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/MacOS/JavaPluginCocoa", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/MacOS/JavaPluginCocoa", should be -rwxrwxr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/MacOS", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/MacOS", should be drwxrwxr-x , they are drwxr-xr-x .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Localizable.strings", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Localizable.strings", should be -rw-rw-r-- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources", should be drwxrwxr-x , they are drwxr-xr-x .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/version.plist", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/version.plist", should be -rw-rw-r-- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Group differs on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents", should be 80, group is 0.

Permissions differ on "Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents", should be drwxrwxr-x , they are drwxr-xr-x .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacSyncManager.framework/Versions/A/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacSyncManager.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DotMacSyncHelper.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacSyncManager.framework/Versions/A/Resources/dotmacsyncui.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DotMacLegacy.framework/Versions/A/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeDirectory", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeSignature", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .

Permissions differ on "System/Library/SystemProfiler/SPDisplaysReporter.spreporter/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources", should be ?--------- , they are -rw-r--r-- .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience most of those are Apple's own patches not being very clean.  You'll find that the symlinks are to a versioned tree for the plugin, much as with the frameworks that have `Versions/A` subtrees.

I'm not sure what to make of the `should be ?---------` ones, though; that suggests garbage in BOM files.  I'd use `pkgutil --file-info` to find the right package file and then examine it with other `pkgutil` commands and/or `lsbom` to see what's messed up, but you'd have to know something about Apple's package format to make sense of it.

Comment: Mac OS X: Disk Utility's Repair Disk Permissions messages that you can safely ignore: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1448